# AWS CloudFormation Retain Deployed Endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

Is there any way to retain the endpoints from previous deployment? I have gone through **CloudFormation DeletionPolicy** but it is available only for resources not for endpoints.

To be precise I have an serverless application which has 5 lambda functions and more than 100 endpoints while i try to deploy i get below error

> The Cloud Formation template is invalid: Template format error: Number of resources, 232, is greater than maximum allowed, 200

Since there is no native support for nested stacks in serverless, I am planning to upload my application in multiple chunks (like i will upload few endpoints in 1st deployment and upload remaining in 2nd deployment). But during my 2nd deployment 1st deployment endpoints are getting deleted. Is there any way to fix this? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: How did you get to 100 endpoints with only 5 lambda functions? 20 endpoints per lambda function? That's even more than the number of possible HTTP methods you can use.

Comment: Do you have a custom domain that you own in Route53? I would recommend mapping your own domain name to your endpoints rather than relying on the randomly-generated domains from API Gateway.

Comment: FYI i have all the lambda functions in a single service. So ideally i have a single api host with more than 100 resources. Since my app is in development stage I do not have custom domain in Route53

Comment: Manivannan, I don't think you're supposed to put all these functions in a single service. It doesn't fit the microservice style encouraged by serverless